# UPDATE not working when in use with AccessDataSource vb asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-update

I am having problems using an UPDATE command in my asp.net project.  The project allows a user to log in via a login page which matches the username and password to a record in the database and saves the username as a cookie.  I then have a settings page which I want to allow a user to edit their account details but when I use the UPDATE function the query is executed without any errors but the update doesn't occur.  I am using an AccessDataSource and an UpdateCommand hopefully someone can find a problem with my code and steer my in the correct direction.
Thanks in advance

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)


    Dim sqlcmd As String
    sqlcmd = "SELECT FirstName, SecondName, UserName, DOB, Password FROM UserTable WHERE UserName = '" & Request.Cookies("UserInfo")("userName") & "'"
    AccessDataSource1.SelectCommand = sqlcmd

    If (Not Page.IsPostBack) Then

        Dim sqlcmd2 As String
        sqlcmd2 = "UPDATE [UserTable] SET [FirstName] = ?, [SecondName] = ?, [UserName] = ?, [DOB] = ?, [Password] = ? WHERE [UserID] = ? AND ISNULL (([FirstName] = ?) OR ([FirstName] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL)) AND (([SecondName] = ?) OR ([SecondName] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL)) AND (([UserName] = ?) OR ([UserName] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL)) AND (([DOB] = ?) OR ([DOB] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL)) AND (([Password] = ?) OR ([Password] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL))"
        AccessDataSource1.UpdateCommand = sqlcmd2

    End If

End Sub
```

---

```
<form id="webform" runat="server">
    <div id="content">
     <asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" DataSourceMode = "DataSet" runat="server" 
            ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" DataFile="~/Database.mdb" 
            OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"  
            UpdateCommand = "UPDATE [UserTable] SET [FirstName] = ?, [SecondName] = ?, [UserName] = ?, [DOB] = ?, [Password] = ? WHERE [UserID] = ? AND ISNULL (([FirstName] = ?) OR ([FirstName] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL)) AND (([SecondName] = ?) OR ([SecondName] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL)) AND (([UserName] = ?) OR ([UserName] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL)) AND (([DOB] = ?) OR ([DOB] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL)) AND (([Password] = ?) OR ([Password] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL))">

         <UpdateParameters>
             <asp:Parameter Name="UserID" Type="Int32" />
             <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
             <asp:Parameter Name="SecondName" Type="String" />
             <asp:Parameter Name="UserName" Type="String" />
             <asp:Parameter Name="DOB" Type="String" />
             <asp:Parameter Name="Password" Type="String" />
             <asp:Parameter Name="original_UserID" Type="Int32" />
             <asp:Parameter Name="original_FirstName" Type="String" />
             <asp:Parameter Name="original_FirstName" Type="String" />
             <asp:Parameter Name="original_SecondName" Type="String" />
             <asp:Parameter Name="original_SecondName" Type="String" />
             <asp:Parameter Name="original_UserName" Type="String" />
             <asp:Parameter Name="original_UserName" Type="String" />
             <asp:Parameter Name="original_DOB" Type="String" />
             <asp:Parameter Name="original_DOB" Type="String" />
             <asp:Parameter Name="original_Password" Type="String" />
             <asp:Parameter Name="original_Password" Type="String" />
         </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:AccessDataSource>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1">
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
<div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Sorry if it is all a bit messy but this is my first post and I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
accessdatasource1.update()
```